# Empty plots from my dynamics

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot following dynamics but it does not work.
Please provide some tips to correct my code.
Thank you.

```
(* Preamble *)
Unprotect[In, Out];
Clear[In, Out];

(* Make parameters *)
eta = 0.34 ;(* Elasticity of labor in production *)
gamma = -1;
theta = 1;
n = 0.05;
rho = 0.042;
r = 0.042;

(* Equilibrium from optimality conditions *)
cdynamic = (1/(1 - gamma))*(eta*(theta^(1 - eta))*(k^(eta - 1)) - 
  rho - n) == 0;
csolution = FindRoot[cdynamic, {k, 2}];
kss = k /. csolution[[1]]
capdynamic = (kss^eta) * (theta^(1 - eta)) - n * kss - c == 0;
capsolution = FindRoot[capdynamic, {c, 1}];
css = c /. capsolution[[1]]

(* Linearization around the steady state *)
w11 = eta*theta^(1 - eta)*k^(eta - 1) - n;
w12 = -1;
w21 = (1/(1 - gamma))*eta*(eta - 1)*theta^(1 - eta)*k^(eta - 2);
w22 = (1/(1 - gamma))*(eta*theta^(1 - eta)*k^(eta - 1) - rho - n);

MatrixForm[linearsystem = {{w11, w12}, {w21, w22}}];

(* Eigenvalues *)
Det[linearsystem];
eigens = Eigenvalues[linearsystem];
mu1 = eigens[[2]]
mu2 = eigens[[1]]


(* Effect of Parental leave Act *)
theta1 = 0.5;
k1 = (r/(eta*theta1^(1 - eta)))^(1/(eta - 1))

k[t_] = k1 + (k1 - kss)*Exp[mu1*t];
c[t_] = css + ((mu1 - w11)/w12)*(k1 - kss)*Exp[mu1*t];

Plot[k[t], {t, 0, 1000}, GridLines -> Automatic]
Plot[c[t], {t, 0, 1000}, GridLines -> Automatic]

Quit[]
```

Comment: An empty plot means you don't have real numeric results. Try `Table[k[t],{t,0,1000,100}]` to see what you're trying to plot.

Comment: Thank you @JohnDoty. It is a great help.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `k` is not defined. If you define it, you get the expected result

```
(*Make parameters*) eta = 0.34;(*Elasticity of labor in production*) \
gamma = -1;
theta = 1;
n = 0.05;
rho = 0.042;
r = 0.042;

(*Equilibrium from optimality conditions*)
cdynamic = (1/(1 - gamma))*(eta*(theta^(1 - eta))*(k^(eta - 1)) - 
      rho - n) == 0;
csolution = FindRoot[cdynamic, {k, 2}];
kss = k /. csolution[[1]];
capdynamic = (kss^eta)*(theta^(1 - eta)) - n*kss - c == 0;
capsolution = FindRoot[capdynamic, {c, 1}];
css = c /. capsolution[[1]];

(*Linearization around the steady state*)
w11 = eta*theta^(1 - eta)*k^(eta - 1) - n;
w12 = -1;
w21 = (1/(1 - gamma))*eta*(eta - 1)*theta^(1 - eta)*k^(eta - 2);
w22 = (1/(1 - gamma))*(eta*theta^(1 - eta)*k^(eta - 1) - rho - n);

linearsystem = {{w11, w12}, {w21, w22}};

(*Eigenvalues*)
Det[linearsystem];
eigens = Eigenvalues[linearsystem];
mu1 = eigens[[2]];
mu2 = eigens[[1]];


(*Effect of Parental leave Act*)
theta1 = 0.5;
k1 = (r/(eta*theta1^(1 - eta)))^(1/(eta - 1));

kt[t_] := k1 + (k1 - kss)*Exp[mu1*t]
ct[t_] := css + ((mu1 - w11)/w12)*(k1 - kss)*Exp[mu1*t]

{Plot[kt[t] /. k -> kss, {t, 0, 70}, GridLines -> Automatic],
 Plot[ct[t] /. k -> kss, {t, 0, 70}, GridLines -> Automatic]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: I got the result. Thank you Alex, my life saver.